# my django registration form doesn´t validate the data

Tags: django, python-3.x

```
def register(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid() is True:  
            form.save()  
            #log the user in  
        return redirect('/account')  


    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)
```

If i try to log in it seems that it doesn't think the data is valid and i don´t know why. It just cleans the registration fields and shows the registrationsite again. I´m using Django 2.1

Comment: What `form.errors` do you get? Also, please fix your code indentation.

Comment: Is there any code when you log in ? between ```form.save()``` and the ```return``` statement ? Do you use ```authenticate``` and ```login``` method ?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. What is that `else` lined up with? What about the two returns? As it is your code is not valid, but we need to see what your indentation *actually* is to see what is happening here.

Comment: ok, sorry i fixed it now!